# can't find controls in page, but only when running via selenium-server

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I have a set of tests that I've developed using the Selenium IDE in Firefox. Tests run fine and all pass. Now I'm trying to port those over to C# and run the tests for IE using MSTest and selenium-server. Here's the sequence of events:

1. Run all tests on Firefox via Selenium IDE. All tests pass.
2. Export tests to MSTest (Nunit export, rename some stuff etc.)
3. Start selenium-server-1.0.3
4. Run the tests in VS2008. Selenium setup is: `selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://localhost/theSite/");`; note that I can browse to `http://localhost/theSite/` just fine.

   4a. Confirm test is launching Firefox. Got result: 
    17:00:30.290 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
    17:00:33.842 INFO - Launching Firefox...
5. First test ( waitForText "Login" in control "ctl00_TopNavBar_LoginStatus1") fails. Can't find the control. 
     `if ("Login" == selenium.GetText("id=ctl00_TopNavBar_LoginStatus1")) break;`
     or 
     `if ("Login" == selenium.GetText("ctl00_TopNavBar_LoginStatus1")) break;`
6. All other tests fail as well -- same reason. Each test has a `waitForText` at the top.

Tried running the test in *chrome, *iexploreproxy and *firefox. All fail for the same reason.

Tried dumping a screenshot using `selenium.CaptureEntirePageScreenshot("c:\\temp\\screenshots\\seleniumSite.png", "background=#FFFFFF");` and the screenshot is just a white bar.

So, my question is, how do I go about debugging this and figuring out what the real problem is? **Clearly the page will render and the tests will pass. It's just when I try those tests in Selenium-RC that it fails** so badly. Does the Selenium IDE have some bugs related to exporting tests to C#? (I have noticed one bug).

Comment: ..could you post your c# selenium test? i've had numerous problems in the past with page loading times, wait commands, xpaths and click(link=exact) not porting to C# correctly, yet they worked fine in the selenium IDE as a HTML test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you executing `selenium.Start()` and `selenium.Open()`? Do you see the page opened in the browser?

Full initialization should be something similar to:

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://localhost/");
selenium.Start();
selenium.Open("/theSite/");
```

**Important Note!** test your IDE tests by starting with an empty page. Also, when using the IDE, if a command only has one parameter put it in the Target field, even if it isn't a control name.

Comment: That was it, the Selenium IDE doesn't create the selenium.Open command.

Comment: Correction: I was always testing from the point of having the page open already.